# How to correctly implement save() input data method from a contact form to Django SQLITe DB?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

How to correctly implement save() to Django SQLITe DB method when taking data  from a contact form input ? Last method tries to save input but it is not working. I have used codes from tutorial on Django contact form sending email. Need to add saving to database functionality.

## view

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
from .models import SendEmail

def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            try:
                send_mail(
                    subject, message, from_email,
                    ['bioinformatics_bel@yahoo.com']
                )
                return redirect('success')
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')

            return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('All right! Thank you for your message.')

def savedata(request):  # want to save data input into the SQLIte  database!! here is something wrong
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            message_object = SendEmail(
                from_email=from_email, subject=subject, message=message)

            message_object.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('success')  # else: form = ContactForm() # unbound form
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})
```

## template

```
<h1>Submit identifier for the  data processing</h1>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

## form

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

## model

```
from django.db import models

class SendEmail(models.Model):
    from_email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.TextField()
    mesage = models.TextField()
```

Comment: if the form is valid you can add `form.save()` in views.py in the `if form.is_valid()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a simple `Form`, your approach it's not bad. If you prefer to migrate the saving logic from your `views.py` to your `forms.py/models.py` you should use a `ModelForm` and as @hansTheFranz commented you could use `.save()` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) from your instantiated form.